# React router: Expected "state" to be defined when moving to /

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React app which doens't have a route to `/` setup, so I placed a redirect inside the `Switch`component, so whenever the user  tries to access home they are redirected to the `UserHome` component.

The `Switch` set-up is as follows:

```
    const AppRoutes = () => (
    <Switch>
    <Redirect
      exact
      from="/"
      to={ROUTES.CITIZEN}
    />
    
    <Route
      exact
      path="/login"
      component={Login}
    />

    <AuthenticatedRouteRedirect
      path={ROUTES.CITIZEN}
      component={UserHome}
    />

    <AuthenticatedRouteRedirect
      path={ROUTES.ADMIN_REPORT_LIST}
      component={reportList}
    />

    <Route
      path="/404"
      component={ErrorView}
    />

    <Route
      component={ErrorView}
    />
</Switch>
```

And `AuthenticatedRouteRedirect` as follows:

```
const AuthenticatedRouteRedirect = ({
  component: Component, path = '', exact = false, ...rest
}) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      exact={exact}
      render={() => (user
        ? <Component {...rest} />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
    />
  );
};

export default AuthenticatedRouteRedirect;
```

And my `UserHome` component:

```
const Dashboard = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Container>
      <ActionMenu />
    </Container>
  </>
);
```

where `ActionMenu` component uses a custom hook called `useReportsLocations`, which its implementation is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getMapPolygons, mexicoMap } from 'core/map-locations';

const useReportsLocations = (selectedGroup) => {
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { state, municipality } = useParams();
  const locationData = React.useMemo(() => {
    const currentSelection = {
      country: mexicoMap,
      state,
      municipality,
      group: selectedGroup,
    };

    return getMapPolygons(currentSelection);
  }, [municipality, selectedGroup, state]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!locationData?.stateData
      || !Object.keys(locationData?.stateData?.municipality
      || {}).includes(municipality)) {
      push('/404');
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [municipality]);

  return {
    locationData,
    state,
    municipality,
  };
};

export default useReportsLocations;
```

Here's a little demo on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rosalind-gwrd9?file=/src/App.js)

But when trying to access `/`, this error message is displayed with the next stacktrace, sorry if it's too large:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the cause for this to happen? And how to fix it?
I'm having a bad time trying to figure out whatever the cause is, but simply I can't.
Thank you for your answer and replies.
Pd

Comment: Can you share the full error message and associated stacktrace? It's unclear where the error originates from.

Comment: Sure. I'll edit further the post, then.

Comment: Can you share also the `UserHome` component? Do you know of anything attempting to access route state? If it's not route state do you know what `state` is being referred to?

Comment: Sure, no problem. And as to something trying yo access state route, there's nothing trying to get access the route `state`

Comment: You know, so far I don't see any overt issues. Think you could create a running codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live.

Comment: Sure. I'll add the codesanbox the.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what's happening.

After I read the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect), as `Redirect` leads me to a route where some params are required, but I don't provide any ones to `to` (as seen in the `ROUTES` file), it has only the placeholders of `{ROUTES.CITIZEN}` route, and `path-to-regexp@^1.7.0` will complaint that it has been passed nothing and coudn't not resolve to anything.

This behaviour is expected.